# Flutter app startup crash on device (apk) but works on debug

Tags: android, flutter, apk, release

App works fine when I run as debug mode on emulator and USB debugging / Wireless Debugging on device but when I build an APK as release and run it on a device the app crashes on startup. I can see the following error in the logcat. My compile SDK version is 33 and device Android version is 13.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-2
    Process: mt.com.nectar.nectar_warehouse_management, PID: 28632
    Z0.b: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at V2.a.f(Unknown Source:46)
        at R2.n.run(Unknown Source:26)
        at R2.n.call(Unknown Source:0)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at u2.n.e(Unknown Source:0)
        at u2.o.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at t2.k0.b(Unknown Source:10)
        at H1.f.get(Unknown Source:82)
        at w1.a.get(Unknown Source:13)
        at G1.f.l(Unknown Source:2)
        at G1.c.get(Unknown Source:52)
        at H1.d.get(Unknown Source:33)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: t2.T0.values []
        at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:272)
        at java.lang.Enum.-$$Nest$smenumValues(Unknown Source:0)
        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:279)
        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
        at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
        at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:291)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2461)
        at java.util.EnumSet.getUniverse(EnumSet.java:412)
        at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:114)
        at java.util.EnumSet.of(EnumSet.java:240)
        at u2.n.<clinit>(Unknown Source:92)
        at u2.n.e(Unknown Source:0) 
        at G1.f.l(Unknown Source:2) 
        at N2.f.d(Unknown Source:41) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: t2.T0.values []
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2103)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2081)
        at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:269)
        at java.lang.Enum.-$$Nest$smenumValues(Unknown Source:0) 
        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:279) 
        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277) 
        at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63) 
        at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:291) 
        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2461) 
        at java.util.EnumSet.getUniverse(EnumSet.java:412) 
        at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:114) 
        at java.util.EnumSet.of(EnumSet.java:240) 
        at u2.n.<clinit>(Unknown Source:92) 
        at u2.n.e(Unknown Source:0) 
        at u2.o.a(Unknown Source:0) 
        at w1.a.get(Unknown Source:13) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Edit 1:
My app\build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdk 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mt.com.nectar.nectar_warehouse_management"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
    namespace 'mt.com.nectar.nectar_warehouse_management'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mt.com.nectar.nectar_warehouse_management">
   <application
        android:label="Nectar Warehouse Management"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo_green">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was caused by shrinking resources / minifying the code. A workaround was to set the shrinkResources, minifyEnabled, multiDexEnabled to false in the app\build.

```
release {
          
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),
                    "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
```

I suspect the issue might be due to a package calling a method / variable that cannot be found due to the minifying of code.